# Python on VSC (MacOs) running line of code with root/sudo permission (using Scapy)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scapy

I'm running a port scanner algorithm on Python 3 using VSC on Mac. When running the Scapy function, or any other type of scanner, I get the following error:
Scapy_Exception: Permission denied: could not open /dev/bpf0. Make sure to be running Scapy as root ! (sudo)

The code I am using

```
from scapy.all import *

ports = [25,80,53,443,445,8080,8443]

def SynScan(host):
    ans,unans = sr(IP(dst=host)/TCP(dport=ports,flags="S"),timeout=2,verbose=0)
    print("Open ports at %s:" % host)
    for (s,r,) in ans:
        if s.haslayer(TCP) and r.haslayer(TCP):
            if s[TCP].dport == r[TCP].sport:
                print(s[TCP].dport)

def DNSScan(host):
    ans,unans = sr(IP(dst=host)/UDP(dport=53)/DNS(rd=1,qd=DNSQR(qname="google.com")),timeout=2,verbose=0)
    if ans:
        print("DNS Server at %s"%host)
    
host = "8.8.8.8"

SynScan(host)
DNSScan(host)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run this script as root user.

```
sudo python script.py
```

do install scapy as root user.

Comment: With `sudo python script.py` I get invalid syntax. How would I install Scapy as root user?

Comment: try ```sudo python -V```, It's probably python v2. If it's indeed the case, do ```sudo python3 script.py```.

Comment: To install scapy as root user, either ```sudo pip install scapy``` or ```sudo pip3 install scapy```. Similar version issue as most linux distros provides two version of python(python => v2 and python3 => v3)

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. Turns out Scapy always requires root/sudo permission.